# ListView's ItemContainerStyle blocks Column Item Binding on GridView

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, itemcontainerstyle

Why does the implementation of `ItemContainerStyle` (*detailed below*) cause the individual data column bindings to fail on an otherwise working `ListView`/`GridView`?

Here is the visual result of the failure where the total items in 3 rows are shown but not the individual column items:

[image]

Implementation without the overridden `ItemContainerStyle`:

[image]

---

**Actual Goal** Before answering the question consider what my ultimate goal is for an alternate workaround. I want a `GridView` like structure where each **row** has a *drop shadow*; preferably shown on the selected item/on hover operation to make the row pop. *As somewhat shown on the failure example above*

---

**Code**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource People}">

                            <!--Comment this out to see working display-->
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Grid Background="White" Margin="20">
                        <Grid.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect />
                        </Grid.Effect>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <!--End Failure Point-->
<ListView.View>
    <GridView >
        <GridViewColumn Header="First" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=First}"  />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Last"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Last}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Phone" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Phone}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

---

To reproduce you will need

**StaticResource Data defined in Xaml**

```
xmlns:model="clr-namespace:{your namespace}.Model"

<UserControl.Resources>
    <model:People x:Key="People">
        <model:Person First="Joe" Last="Smith" Phone="303-555-5555"/>
        <model:Person First="Jenny" Last="Johnson" Phone="720-867-5309" />
        <model:Person First="Frank" Last="Wright" Phone="202-555-5555" />
    </model:People>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**People.cs** *in Model namspace*

```
public class People : List<Person> { }

public class Person
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ContentPresenter` is the wrong node type to use for the `ControlTemplate` of the `ItemContainerStyle`.

To fix change `ContentPresenter` to `GridViewRowPresenter` and also remove `ContentTemplate` as such:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Grid Background="White" Margin="20">
        <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect />
        </Grid.Effect>
        <GridViewRowPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"                                  
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Visual Result**

[image]